# Trouble linking opencv C++ library on Windows 11 using vs code

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, dll, windows-11

I am trying to create a DLL on Windows 11 using CMake. I want to read 2 video streams coming into a single USB port and the DLL should split the streams into 2 separate video streams for a downstream application to consume.
I cant seem to even get started. I have setup CMake v0.0.17 and C/C++ v1.18.5 extensions on vs code.
Here are the device specifications

```
Processor   13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1355U   1.70 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.6 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   Pen and touch support with 10 touch points
```

and Windows specification

```
Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 23H2
Installed on    ‎12/‎23/‎2023
OS build    22631.3007
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22681.1000.0
```

Over the past week, I have tried all sorts of combinations on CMakeLists.txt file without much luck. This is the one I have now.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(video_split_dll)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Users/ctipp/vcpkg")  # Ensure vcpkg is in CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

# Point to OpenCV4 specifically
set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/Users/ctipp/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/opencv4")
set(OpenCV_LIB_DIR "C:/Users/ctipp/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib")


# Adjust other package locations accordingly (if needed)
set(Protobuf_DIR "C:/Users/ctipp/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/protobuf")
set(quirc_DIR "C:/Users/ctipp/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/quirc")

# If using vcpkg-installed TIFF, adjust path accordingly
set(TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR "C:/Users/ctipp/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include")
set(TIFF_LIBRARY "C:/Users/ctipp/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/tiff.lib")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS "C:/Users/ctipp/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib")
find_package(TIFF)
find_package(Protobuf)
find_package(quirc)


message("OpenCV library paths: ${OpenCV_LIB_DIR}")  # Print OpenCV library paths
message("OpenCV include paths: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")  # Print OpenCV include paths
message("OpenCV libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")  # Print OpenCV libraries
message("Linked libraries: ${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS}")  # Print linked libraries
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_library(opencv_dll SHARED video_processing.cpp)
target_link_libraries(opencv_dll PRIVATE opencv_core opencv_imgproc)
```

I have learnt to use vcpkg to install opencv and other dependent libraries. Corresponding c++ code is

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

extern "C" {

    __declspec(dllexport) void process_image(const cv::Mat& input_image, cv::Mat& output_image) {
        // Perform image processing using OpenCV
        cv::cvtColor(input_image, output_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);  // Example: Convert to grayscale
    }

}
```

I have looked at different sources for answer and none of them seem to work. Here are some observations. When I install opencv using vcpkg, it seem to install both opencv and opencv4 libraries. In the `target_link_libraries` part, I cant seem to include opencv4 libraries. During build time, I seem to get unable to locate library error. When I use the opencv library, I get an error `undefined reference to cv::cvtColor(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int, int)`
Appreciate any inputs/suggestions.

Comment: What compiler do you use? MSVC or MinGW? What tutorial did you follow that suggested integrating vcpkg into CMake like that?

Comment: I am using MinGW compiler. I cant seem to recollect a particular tutorial to integrating vcpkg into cmake.

Comment: You should have zero vcpkg-specific stuff in your CMakeLists.txt, and zero hardcoded paths. I believe you just need to do `find_package(whatever)`, and `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=...` to the mingw toolchain file that comes with vcpkg.

Comment: But honestly, I'd use [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) instead of vcpkg for MinGW. MSYS2 has MinGW as its primary focus, while for vcpkg it's a second-class citizen.

Comment: ***I am using MinGW compiler*** There are vcpkg triplets for MinGW. The `x64-windows`  triplet is for msvc x64  and will be mostly incompatible with MinGW. And yes it would be far easier to just use msys2 and have pacman install the proper MinGW binaries.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will change the compiler to MSYS2 and revert back.

Comment: Forgot to say: in MSYS2 `find_package(whatever)` should just work out of the box, with no extra configuration.

Comment: [https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-opencv](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-opencv) are the opencv packages available in the msys2 repository depending in what environment you selected [https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/)

Comment: Overcame some issues building helloworld using MSYS2. I then installed `mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv` from the above link. I have constructed cmakelists.txt based on above recommendation. However, when I build, I get error `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::cvtColor(class cv::debug_build_guard`. I also see a warning `warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86' `.  Trying to see if this is a configuration issue or a installation issue.

Comment: my CMakelist.txt 
```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)                           
PROJECT(split_videostream)                                         
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "c:/msys64/mingw64/lib")
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_library(opencv_dll SHARED video_processing.cpp) 
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (opencv_dll ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```
Not sure if I am making an error in the configuration.

Comment: Apologies, I installed https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-opencv?repo=ucrt64 as my environment seem to be mingw64.

Comment: Linking error and the above warning persists.

Comment: I was able to resolve warnings. I had to chose the right cmake kit. I now have the right target architecture. But the linking errors seem to persist. `[build] video_processing.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::cvtColor(class cv::debug_build_guard::_InputArray const &,class cv::debug_build_guard::_OutputArray const &,int,int) referenced in function process_image [C:\Users\ctipp\projects\video_splitter\build\videosplit_dll.vcxproj]
[build] C:\Users\ctipp\projects\video_splitter\build\Debug\videosplit_dll.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals `

Comment: 1. Please use `@username` when replying, otherwise we don't get notifications. 2. MSYS2 installs libs for MinGW, and the error message in your original question ("undefined reference") sounds like it came from MinGW. But now you're using MSVC, for which vcpkg would be a good choice. What compiler do you actually want to be using? 3. And again, no hardcoded paths in CMakeLists.txt. Remove `set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "c:/msys64/mingw64/lib")`.

Comment: Thank you @HolyBlackCat.. I am using gcc version 13.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project). I used pacman to install gcc using `pacman -Syu mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain`. I have removed `set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "c:/msys64/mingw64")`. The linking errors `LNK2019` and `LNK1120` persist.

Comment: Because your CMake isn't using GCC, it's using MSVC. Make sure the CMake you're using is installed from MSYS2 as well, and that you run it (and the subsequent compilation) from the MSYS2 terminal.

Comment: Ah! Makes sense. Let me add that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - I have made changes to cmake setting to use msys2. `/msys64/mingw64/bin/cmake.exe --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -SC:/Users/ctipp/projects/video_splitter -Bc:/Users/ctipp/projects/video_splitter/build -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T host=x86 -A x64`. Thats the cmake command. I still get the same linking error while cmake: build. I dont quite get it when you say "and that you run it (and the subsequent compilation) from the MSYS2 terminal.". I am currently running it from vs code.

Comment: How do you even run a VS project from VSC? (You know they're different things, right?) Clean the build dir, re-run CMake with `-GNinja` instead of `-G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T host=x86 -A x64` (make sure you install Ninja from MSYS2 too), then build with `cmake --build your_build_dir`.